# Run application on lock and unlock on android

Tags: android, android-intent, screen-lock

I have an application installed on Android. I want to launch that application each time the screen is locked or unlocked.

- Is there an application that can do this job ?
- If not, and if I should code it, do I have to worry about intents and the manifest of the already installed application?

Answer (score 1):

Not everybody locks their phone. All 5 phones in my family are not locked or unlocked. You can monitor ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF. Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing :) I had to write an application to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app named "After Unlock" available in the Google Play store. Free and the description (I haven't ever used it) makes it sound like it's exactly what you're looking for, at least in the 'unlock' department. There are probably others. I use a non-free app called 'Tasker' that's far more elaborate and could do the whole job and just about anything else you could dream up, but as I said, it ain't free.